# Error when declaring a String by assigning a value from a method in c#

Tags: c#, string

I am learning C# in Unity but I am receiving a weird error. Error is saying "Expression denotes a `variable', where a`method group' was expected"

This is the line that gives the error:

```
string walkingDir = walkingDir();
```

This is the walkingDir() method:

```
private string walkingDir(){
return "str";}
```

Replacing

```
string walkingDir = walkingDir();
```

with

```
string walkingDir = "str";
```

works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because the name of the function is the-same as the name of the variable which are both *"walkingDir"*.

You have to either **rename** the function or the variable.

```
string walkingDir = getWalkingDir();
```

and

```
private string getWalkingDir()
{
    return "str";
}
```

---

Another way to fix this **without** re-naming the variables is to use the `this` keyword to tell the compiler to use the local function name instead of the variable name.

This should work too:

```
string walkingDir = this.walkingDir();
```

and

```
private string walkingDir()
{
    return "str";
}
```

Even though that should work, I encourage you to prevent naming your variable or function name the-same.

Comment: ah. JAVA had no such rules.

Comment: Well, this is C# and I am not a Java programmer and can't tell if that's true. The rule makes sense though because how can you tell which variable you are referring to if you name them the-same.

Comment: () allows me to differentiate.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your variable and method have the same name.  Change the name of your variable and it will compile.  E.g.

```
string walkDir = walkingDir();
```